# Naming of mathematical elements in GMM?

Tags: terminology, notation, generalized-moments

I'm struggling with the naming of different elements in GMM. There doesn't seem to be consistency in the literature. What do we even call the *moment integrand* $g$? I take a stab below with help from Wikipedia.

#### Detail

[The wiki on GMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_method_of_moments) describes the set-up of GMM using

$$m(\theta_0) \equiv \operatorname{E}[\,g(Y_t,\theta_0)\,]$$
$$\hat{m}(\theta) \equiv \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T g(Y_t,\theta).$$

I believe they imply the names of these things are:

- $m(\theta)$: a *population/theoretical moment function*
- $\operatorname{E}[\,g(Y_t,\theta_0)\,]$: a *population/theoretical generalized moment*
- $\operatorname{E}[\,g(Y_t,\theta_0)\,]=c$: a *population/theoretical generalized moment condition*
- $\operatorname{E}[\,g(Y_t,\theta_0)\,]=0$: a *population/theoretical generalized moment condition for GMM.*
- $\hat{m}(\theta)$: a *sample generalized moment function*
- $\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T g(Y_t,\theta)$: a *sample generalized moment*
- $g(Y_t,\theta)$???

Do we just call $g(Y_t,\theta)$ a *moment integrand function*? That seems clunky, especially if we want to refer to these functions on their own, outside of the GMM model-estimation context. What about *model statistic*? I like that it's more general. But strictly speaking, these aren't statistics since they're functions of parameters. So what about *model statistic generator* or *model statistic function*?

In most materials on GMM, no one even gives this thing a name. Those that do usually call it something or other which conflicts with the above terminology, e.g., *moment function*. Maybe the above terminology needs to change? Can someone suggestion a consistent naming scheme here?

UPDATE: For my particular use-case, I don't use GMM, but my set-up is very similar. The $g$ actually take the form $\ell(f(Y_t,\theta),A_t)$ where $\ell$ is a loss like *squared error*, $f(Y_t,\theta)$ is some *model statistic function* (My terminology. I say *function* to emphasize that a statistic is technically a transformation of raw sample data and is *not* a function of model parameters. This is. So when evaluated at specific model parameters $\theta$, it produces a *model statistic*), and $A_t$ are some *targets* or *actuals*. Since $\ell$ is a loss, $\operatorname{E}[\ell(\cdot)]>0$. There is no hope of making $\ell$ an *orthogonality condition function* in this form. So, in my more specific setting, I'm inclined to call the $g=\ell$ *losses*, $f$ *model statistic functions*, and $\hat{m}(\theta)$ *cost functions*. If someone answers with a better solution, I'll take that as the answer. Otherwise, I'm going to take this solution of mine to be the answer.

Comment: do you really need a name for all these parts?

Comment: @Aksakal the $g$ is most important to me. I think the others are probably fine. But I include them here because even these are not consistent across the literature.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to call it a name, I suggest "orthogonality condition function" for $g(Y_t,\theta)$. That's how it's referred to in Hansen's [paper](https://teach.business.uq.edu.au/courses/FINM6905/files/module-1/readings/Hansen.pdf): "Large Sample Properties of Generalized Method of Moments Estimators", see Assumption 2.3

Comment: Ok, but what would you call a $g(Y_t,\theta)$ such that $\operatorname{E}[g(Y_t,\theta)]\neq 0$. Doesn't seem right having its name depend on the particular condition it's used for in GMM, no?

Comment: @lowndrul, it's a condition, it may or may not hold, that shouldn't grant the name change

Comment: For my use case, I'm not actually using GMM but, rather, minimizing a weighted sum of these functions by taking as given data $Y_t$ and choosing $\theta$. These functions are distances between $Y_t$ and $\theta$ like squared-error. The set-up is very similar to GMM. But since $g>0$, there's no hope of satisfying any orthogonality conditions in the given form.